# Is it possible to have VLC reread automatically an XSPF file between songs using Lua?

Tags: php, lua, vlc, xspf

First of I have no experience in Lua, just came by it while searching for an answer to my question here on StackOverflow and the internet. If there is any other method you know of that might work I'd very much appreciate hearing it.

So what I'm gearing up to do is to have a basic webpage that uses php and a Mysql database to allow users to vote up or down songs. At a specific time the top song is put as the next song/first song in an XSPF playlist XML.

And what I need to find out how (or if its possible) to have VLC reread the XSPF file between songs so that it uses the updated playlist. I have seen examples of playlist creation in VLC using Lua scripts but before I dive into how to do that I was wondering if this was at all possible?

Also if you know of any other way of putting up a similar settup without the use of one or more of these things I've just mentioned I'd also like to know.

Comment: I've not found a solution yet but I've started programming an extension for vlc that will do what I'm trying to do. Once I've done that, or hit a wall I'll post the results.

Comment: I've decided that just using the http interface in VLC and programming onto that is better. I couldn't figure out a way to make the lua script execute when I wanted it to.